# Excel Formula to convert date time to Military time ddmm hhmm?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help formatting a datetime field in excel to military time as ddmm hhmm. There should be a space in between ddmm and hhmm.
For example i have 6/16/2021, 5:15pm - this should change to 1606 1715

Comment: If your data is an actual date (number), and not text, then you just need to apply custom formatting, `ddmm hmm`, no formula needed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFEmW.png

Comment: It is an actual date. As is how i mentioned in the example. I tried formatting but it really does not give me the desired format of ddmm hhmm. it simply converts it to military time which is not my requirement. I do not need the year. I need a space between date and time  etc.

Comment: As mentioned, `ddmm hmm`, demonstrated in the screenshot.

Comment: Can you guide me through the custom formatting please. Like the steps.

Comment: There's only one step: type `ddmm hmm` in the Type box under the Custom category, not sure what the issue is on your end. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtxFT.png

Comment: Hi Bigben, so i selected the entire column, went to custom formatting entered ddmm hhmm and say ok nothing happens.

Comment: Then your dates are text. In Excel, a datetime is a formatted *number*.

Comment: My fault there was a " , " in between . Thank you.

Comment: `=TEXT(A1,"ddmm hhmm")` would accomplish the same, but in different column.Both solution above and this do not work if your dates are not a value, but stored as text.